# Adding a folder on the local network to the list of "local-trusted" places

Tags: flash, security, sandbox, access-violation

I have a SWF file located at the local network in the public shared folder that I do not control over trying to read the external file on the local network.

I am currently hitting instead an security violation

```
Error #2148: SWF file file://....mySWF.swf cannot access local resource file://...config.xml"
```

I've added the network path where SWF an XML file resides to "trusted locations" via Flash Player Global Settings.

The added network path is successfully displayed at the list of "trusted locations" within Global Settings Manager, but it does not look like Flash Player is able to really parse the local network path as a "trusted location"

FP 10.3.181.23, Win XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows I have previously fixed this by mapping network drives to a drive letter.  That seemed to fool FP into trusting the location.

Browse to the folder you wish to map (it doesn't have to be the one your files reside in, but can be further up the tree), right click and select `Map network drive`. Once you've allocated a drive letter you will have to add the new path to the Global Settings panel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, while your answer is reasonable, just FYI in my case it did not help to resolve "security violation" issue, well, just moved to the local drive file setup.

Comment: Is the config.xml in the same folder as the SWF, and if not, did you try adding the location of the xml as a trusted location?